# Is there a better way to use rollbar error reporting with flask?

Tags: python, python-decorators, rollbar

I just came across [rollbar](https://rollbar.com) and wanted to include it in my Python project.

This is the standard way in which I am told to implement rollbar from the website.

```
import rollbar

rollbar.init('KEY')
try:
    a = s
except:
    rollbar.report_exc_info()
```

Is there a better way to implement this without going through all my `try except` blocks and replacing them with `rollbar.report_exc_info()`

Can there be a decorator implementation for this?
My current project is a Flask app that provides API's to end users.

Comment: What project is this? For Django there is a middleware that will
report all exceptions to Rollbar.

Comment: I have a flask app that provides an API's.

Comment: https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-flask-example/blob/master/hello.py Check this out.

Comment: exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give your comment as an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example for rollbar integration in Flask apps.

https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-flask-example/blob/master/hello.py

```
@app.before_first_request
def init_rollbar():
    """init rollbar module"""
    rollbar.init(
        # access token for the demo app: https://rollbar.com/demo
        'fc316ac1f7404dc28af26d5baed1416c',
        # environment name
        'flasktest',
        # server root directory, makes tracebacks prettier
        root=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),
        # flask already sets up logging
        allow_logging_basic_config=False)

    # send exceptions from `app` to rollbar, using flask's signal system.
    got_request_exception.connect(rollbar.contrib.flask.report_exception, app)
```